# Not able to connect to snowflake through DBEAVER timed out

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

I have a DBeaver 7.3. and snowflake driver version: *jdbc 3.9.2.jar*

Received the below error message even after proxy setup.

```
JDBC driver encountered communication error. 
Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: Connect to xxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443 [ Connection timed out: connect
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The communication error usually appears when the required snowflake hosts and ports are not opened at the proxy end. This can be verified by using SnowCD Connectivity Diagnostic Tool on the client machine.

To know how to use SnowCD, Check https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/snowcd.html#snowcd-connectivity-diagnostic-tool